# Bitmap only displays correctly with PROGMEM keyword

Tags: arduino-leonardo, atmega32u4

I have a bitmap to draw defined as below.

```cpp
PROGMEM const unsigned char ship1 [] = {0x18, 0x3C, 0x7E, 0xFF, 0x81, 0xC3};
```

It is then used by the `arduboy` library's draw slow bitmap function like so:

```cpp
arduboy.drawSlowXYBitmap(5,5, ship1, 8 , 6, WHITE);
```

Can anyone explain to me why the bitmap only draws correctly with the `PROGMEM` keyword? I omitted it at first and it causes the bitmap to look completely different.

I see that this keyword makes the data get written to flash instead of SRAM.

The hardware I am using is the Arduboy.

The `arduboy.drawSlowXYBitmap()` function is from https://github.com/Arduboy/Arduboy

```cpp
void Arduboy::drawSlowXYBitmap
(int16_t x, int16_t y, const uint8_t *bitmap, uint8_t w, uint8_t h, uint8_t color)
{
  // no need to dar at all of we're offscreen
  if (x+w < 0 || x > WIDTH-1 || y+h < 0 || y > HEIGHT-1)
    return;

  int16_t xi, yi, byteWidth = (w + 7) / 8;
  for(yi = 0; yi < h; yi++) {
    for(xi = 0; xi < w; xi++ ) {
      if(pgm_read_byte(bitmap + yi * byteWidth + xi / 8) & (128 >> (xi & 7))) {
        drawPixel(x + xi, y + yi, color);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Imagine two programs identical apart from the `PROGMEM` keyword. The program only contains the lines mentioned above and the relevant calls to refresh the display. What I want an explanation of is why I get a garbled image without it and a fine image with it.

Comment: It depends on the application code (which you didn't give us!). If the code uses `pgm_read_byte` to read from the pointer, it will read from program memory (flash). Else, from RAM. If you change a variable's storage from PROGMEM to RAM but don't adapt the code, errors like yours happen (reading from the wrong mem addr).

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I have added the only other relevant line in the code but this is a library call so I will have to find the source code. In both cases the variable is a const the only difference was the Progmem keyword.

Comment: I was right on the money: https://github.com/Arduboy/Arduboy/blob/master/src/Arduboy.cpp#L630

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Ok that makes sense and it clearly works fine with the progmem keyword but could you explain why this happens then when the only change is whether the code is built with the keyword or not.

Comment: Because without the PROGMEM keyword your doesn't put the data in the same place that the library is going to look for it.  You put it in SRAM and the library is looking at the same address in flash.  Imagine sending a letter to the right street address but with the wrong city and zip.

Comment: @Delta_G Perfect that answers it. The function looks in flash and not SRAM. Max said it looked in flash first before looking in SRAM which confused me.

Comment: The point I wanted to make was that if it does `pgm_read_byte( somePointer )` then it will read from flash, else, meaning "direct dereference" using `*somePointer` or `somePointer[i]` will load from RAM.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Ok that makes sense.If you put your comments in an answer I will mark it as the answer. Thanks.